# Process.start with application & filename as variables

Tags: c#, process

Have been searching, but surprisingly could not find this specific question:

With C# I want (by clicking a button in a form) to run a certain file, with an certain application.

When using "Process.start(variable)" I can only pick one of the two.

And by using "Process.startinfo.filename" (like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename?view=net-5.0) this also seems to be the case.

Isn't is possible to just combine both in some "easy" way?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by combine?

Comment: @TimothyG. giving both variables. so telling it which file to open, and telling it with which program to open it.

Comment: After seeing the answer posted, your question makes sense now, *but questions should stand on their own.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would run a file with an application using a command argument (i.e. 'notepad.exe file.txt').

If that is possible with the application(s) you are attempting to launch, then you would simply need to set the `Filename` property of `StartInfo` to the name, if in the PATH, or the full path of the application and the `Arguments` property to the path of the file.

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\{pathToFile}\\file.txt";
process.Start();
```

The above code would launch notepad opening file.txt. You can simply replace the `FileName` and `Arguments` with variables containing the paths to the application and file.

Comment: hmm it's not giving me the result I expected. But don't know if this has to do with your answer or with the program running. When running a Workbench with the FME quicktranslator it doesn't give me the correct output. But guess you're answer might be correct, so I'll consider the question solved. Thanks

Comment: If anyone wonders or reads this topic in the future: the reason it wasn't working is there was spatials in the path. You need to use the "$" sign when entering arguments, else process.start doesn't work correctly.